# If we take point (2,1) as the center point and ... then point (3, 3) is transformed into point ___

Tags: geometry, rotations

[image]

So I was practicing for an exam, and through my studying I found this problem. I really don't know how to solve it although the answer must not be too complicated since the question that came with this one were fairly simple. I first thought that maybe I could use vectors to solve this problem. I tried using this equation:

[image]

I noticed that this wouldn't help since I would then have the following equation
:[image]. I would have two variables to solve for using only one equation so I couldnt solve it.

I also thought of using geometry thus making a triangle with two sides equal to sqrt(5) thus it would have an angle of 45 degrees and two of 67.5 degress. I could then proceed to use sine rule but this wouldn't work out for me since I am supposed to do the problem with calculator.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you know the formula for a $45^{\circ}$ rotation about the origin?

Comment: What is $[1-3]$ supposed to mean?

Comment: This is just the slot where I should write my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Translate the center of rotation to the origin, perform the $45^{\circ}$ degree rotation, and then apply the inverse translation.